# MySQL with selecting distinct row

Tags: php, mysql

**Hello there, I have a schema like this, table name feeds**  
Where msg_id is unique and its the primary key of the table

|   msg_id    |commented|
|         1          |       10        |
|         2          |       10        |
|         3          |       10        |
|         4          |       21        |

I want to build a query that would select the last two rows  
 
**The output should go like this**  
 
|   msg_id    |commented|
|         3          |       10        |
|         4          |       21        |

In short the query should return the rows with msg_id which have a distinct commented value

Answer (score 2):

Group by the column ment to be unique and select the highest id for every group

```
select max(msg_id) as msg_id, commented
from your_table
group by commented
```

Comment: Thanks for making my struggle come to an end. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
select max(msg_id), commented from your_table group by commented
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM feeds GROUP BY commented